# JQuery mobile tool-tip popup("close") function is not working in IPhone 5

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, jquery-mobile

In my JQuery Mobile site I've added a tool-tip dialog box to open when the page is load and It'll disappear after 5sec. My code is similar to follows,

```
  <div data-role="popup" id="popupInfo">
     <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).live( 'pagechange',function(event){
     $('#popupInfo').popup("open")
      setTimeout(function() {
      $('#popupInfo').popup("close");
      }, 5000);
  });
   </script>
```

This update is working fine in all devices except in **IPhone 5 iOS 6**. Because when I tried to load my JQuery mobile page with above script in **IPhone 5 iOS 6** device it redirect me to the previous page when the popup closing. I'm not sure what I've missed here but for me it looks like jQuery Mobile **popup("close")** function is not supporting for **IPhone 5 iOS 6**.

Also when the tool-tip load following hash tag text appending to the URL how can we avoid this `#&ui-state=dialog`

Could anyone please let me know how can we solve this issue ?

I've even tried following code also;

```
 $(document).on('pagechange',function(event){
        $('#popupInfo').popup("open").delay(2000).popup("close");

    });
```

But this is not working at all

Comment: A big thanks for pursuing this situation. I'll as soon update you on this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got it. Add `data-history="false"` to the `popupBasic` Popup div.

```
<!-- Button / works without it -->
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>

<!-- Popup #popupBasic -->
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-history="false">
<p>This is a completely basic popup.<p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).live( 'pagechange',function(){
 $('#popupBasic').popup("open")
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('#popupBasic').popup("close");
  }, 5000);
 });

</script>
```

JSfiddle: [Popup](http://jsfiddle.net/zQtvp/1/)

Comment: Thanks for this but still the issue is remain. Plase check my test file with online emulator. Test Link : **http://www.apartmentslanka.com/ztest_calender/zfr/index_a.html**. Online emulator link : **http://iphonetester.com/**

Answer (score 1):

Also  alternatively..jquery mobile surrounds pop-ups with a div having ID = "yourpopupid-popup"
So you can simply hide that div.

> > for example: 
> >       < div id="basic" data-role="popup" > I am pop up< / div >
> >      , then you can close it by :
> >     **$('#basic-popup').hide();**

Answer (score 1):

Use two functions hide() or you can use close() function on clicking the button

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem in using popup for toolbar menu (jQuery Mobile 1.2). For example:

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>

<!-- Popup #popupBasic -->
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-history="false">
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<li><a href='item1.html'>Item1</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Above code doesn't work on iPhone 5 (but works on android, iPhone4 etc). If I change it as below it works.

```
<a data-ajax="false" href='item1.html'>Item1</a>
```