# JQuery .popup("open") not working properly on iOS 9 device

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, worklight-studio

onClick event we call following

1. $("#popupDialog").popup("open");
2. $("#popupDialog").popup("open");
3. $("#username").focus();

the popup appears and suddenly disappear.

We are facing this issue on iOS devices , since we updated ipad and iphone to ios 9 before iOS 9 it was OK.

Mobile Application Platform : JQuery Mobile 1.4.2 using Mobilefirst 6.3 studio

How can we fix this issue ?

Thanks,

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009607/jquery-mobile-tool-tip-popupclose-function-is-not-working-in-iphone-5?rq=1

Comment: @jharig23 I don't think so, cos I didn't have this issue prior to iOS 9. this issue is caused by iOS 9 update compared to your suggested duplicate, although the solution is the same

Answer (score 17):

I added data-history="false" to the pop div and it is is working now

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful, fixed my problems immediately!

Comment: data-history="false" fixes it for me too!  Thank You!  This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. Seems that adding

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit",function(){
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled=false;
});
```

has an effect: the pop-up opens one time. But then after closing, the problem comes back.

Still looking into it...