# I cannot open popup dialog with Phonegap on iOS mobile

Tags: ios, cordova, dialog, popup

I have a strange problem with Phonegap on iOS platform. On Android, "popup" works correctly.
I have this code:

```
<button data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" id="prueba23">Botón</button>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" style="top:-21px">
        <h1>Delete Page?</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main">
        <h3 class="ui-title">Are you sure you want to delete this page?</h3>
        <p>This action cannot be undone.</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#test-ries" data-role="button" data-icon="info"   data-iconpos="notext">Volver</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$('#prueba23').on('tap', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#popupDialog').popup('open');
});
</script>
```

and on iOS platform, at first time that I tap button, popup's appears and dissapears after a second. On second (and third, fourth,...) time, popup works correctly. Only has a strange behaviour at first time that I tap the button.

Here you have an example video that I record: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTkrUr1vpsM&feature=youtu.be
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are testing on iOS 9 and, from the looks of your HTML, using jQuery Mobile in your app. If so, you've come across a bug/"feature" introduced into iOS 9 which is that setting of `window.location.hash` is asynchronous in the iOS 9.0 UIWebview (used by Cordova/Phonegap) - see [this bug report](https://openradar.appspot.com/22186109) for details.

This causes issues when using jQuery Mobile, which by default uses `window.location.hash` to navigate between "pages". It also causes issues with popups/dialogs/select menus which use this mechanism, hence the symptoms you are seeing. Note that Safari on iOS 8 and 9 uses WKWebView not UIWebView, hence JQM sites viewed in the browser on iOS 9 don't encounter these issues.

You can fix these issues on iOS 9.0 Cordova apps by preventing jQuery Mobile from automatically listening/using location.hash:

```
$(document).on("deviceready", function(){
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
});
```

However, I found this had side effects on Android such as causing the hardware back button not to work, so I targeted it specifically at iOS 9 using [cordova-plugin-device](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device):

```
$(document).on("deviceready", function(){
    if(device.platform === "iOS" && parseInt(device.version) === 9){
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    }
});
```

This fixed my navigation and popup issues, but [others have said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32631137/777265) that setting `data-history="false"` on the popup div fixed the issue for them, so if the above doesn't work, try this too.

Alternatively you can use [this plugin](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView) to use the new WKWebView on iOS 8 and 9 with your Cordova app. cordova-ios 3 still uses UIWebView due to [a bug](http://www.openradar.me/18039024) in WKWebView in iOS 8, but the upcoming cordova-ios 4 [will support](https://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/apache-cordova-ios-4-0-0-and-wkwebview-support/) a [WKWebView core plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) for iOS 9+. Note that there are additional considerations when using WKWebView with Cordova/Phonegap apps due to its stricter security, such as requiring CORS headers on XHR responses.

Comment: I had some side effects from changing this globally, and had to resort to setting data-history="false" on each of the popups instead. That worked to resolve this issue for me on iOS 9 with jQM 1.4.2.

Comment: I tried data-history="false" and it doesnt work and when i tried the solution above, it hides my page after i do any mobile page change......... $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#homepage", {transition: "fade"});   and the .hide() stops working..